# Adding extra fields to pydantic BaseModel which are schemas in my FastAPI app

Tags: pydantic

I have a table which I call it `VStatus`, stands for Verification Status, it is meant to keep track of entities that are verified or not.

On the FastAPI OpenAPI docs, the example schema looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it shows the schema for the body of the `POST` request to be:

```
{
  "veri_status": "Unverified",
  "vdesc": "",
  "is_verified": false
}
```

My objective is to have the field `is_verified` calculated automatically after the creation of a record of `VStatus` and the creation should only require two fields `veri_status` and `vdesc`.

Here is the sqlmodel.SQLModel:

```
class VStatusBase(SQLModel):
    veri_status: VerificationStatusEnum = Field(
        default=VerificationStatusEnum.Unverified, nullable=False)
    vdesc: str = Field(default='', sa_column=Column("vdesc", String))
    is_verified: Optional[bool] = Field(default=None)
```

Here are the schemas, as you can see, I try to validate the `is_verified` field by doing some validations on it on the Create and Update schemas.

```
class IVStatusCreate(VStatusBase):
    is_verified: Optional[bool] = is_verified_validator


class IVStatusRead(VStatusBase):
    id: UUID


class IVStatusConciseRead(SQLModel):
    veri_status: VerificationStatusEnum
    is_verified: bool


@optional
class IVStatusUpdate(VStatusBase):
    is_verified: Optional[bool] = is_verified_only_if_veri_status_is_not_none_validator
```

Therefore, my question is, can I make the Create and Update schemas take in `is_verified` as an extra field post-creation, without it being a field visible in the Example Value on OpenAPI?